# Which interval is correct here$?$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, roots, quadratics, interval-arithmetic

The equation $$2\textrm{sin}^2\theta x^2-3\textrm{sin}\theta x+1=0$$ where $\theta \in \left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ has one root lying in the interval

> $(0,1)$

> $(1,2)$

> $(2,3)$

> $(-1,0)$

I know that if $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are of opposite signs then at least $1$ or in general odd number of roots of the equation $f(x)=0$ lie between $a$ and $b$. But I am not able to use this piece of information here, maybe because of two variables. I also tried to assume $\textrm{sin}\theta x$ as $y$ but nothing good came out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Answer given is $(1,2)$

Comment: your item factors nicely, I suppose the sine tends to obscure that

Comment: This is just my opinion.  But I think the question suggests that it does not matter what $\theta$ is, as long as it's in the specified interval.  If the location of the root (in $x$) changed based on $\theta$, then I think that would imply the question would have two correct answers.  So, maybe let $\theta = \pi/3$ and see where that takes you.

Comment: "But I am not able to use this piece of information here, maybe because of two variables". But if it holds for all $\theta \in \left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$ then choose some $\theta$ in this interval and see what happens. That should give you an answer, as the question says it must work for this specific value of $\theta.$ My comment is similar to Doug's...

Comment: Just use the quadratic formula

Comment: Define $t = \; \sin \theta  \; \; x $  and work with $2 t^2 - 3t + 1=0$

Comment: @AdamRubinson i I tried that with $\theta =60°$  but I came up with two different values of $x$

Comment: It does indeed seem that the answer given is wrong.  By simple factoring ($2\sin^2\theta x^2 - 3\sin\theta x +1=(2\sin\theta x -1)(\sin\theta x -1)$ and treating $\sin\theta$ as a constant, there are two roots $x_1 = \frac 1{\sin \theta}$ and $x_2=\frac 1{2\sin\theta}$. As $\frac 1{\sqrt 2} < \sin\theta < 1$(because $\frac \pi 4< \theta < \frac \pi 2$) we have $x_1\in (1,\sqrt 2)\subset (1,2)$ and $x_2\in (\frac 12, \frac{\sqrt 2}2) \subset (0,1)$.  So there is one root in $(0,1)$ and the other in $(1,2)$.

Comment: **Please**, put parentheses !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$:

$$x_\pm = \frac{3\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{9\sin^2\theta-8\sin^2\theta}}{4\sin^2\theta} = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sin\theta} & \text{ or } \\ \frac{1}{2\sin\theta} & \end{cases}$$

because $\sin\theta\in\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt 2},1\right)$ for $\theta\in\left( \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Thus, the *two* roots of $x$ lie in the intervals

$$x_+ = \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\in \left( 1,\sqrt 2\right) \subseteq (1,2) \\
x_- = \frac{1}{2\sin\theta}\in \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right) \subseteq (0,1)$$

The claim that $x$ only has *one* root is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
2\sin^2 \theta x^2 − 3 \sin \theta x +1 & = 0 \\
x & = \frac{3 \sin \theta \pm \sqrt{9 \sin^2 \theta - 8 \sin^2 \theta}}{4 \sin^2 \theta} \\
x & = \frac{3 \pm 1}{4 \sin \theta} \\
x & = \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \; \; \text{or} \; \; x = \frac{1}{2\sin\theta}
\end{align}$
$$ \therefore \, \theta  = (2n+1)\pi - \sin^{-1} \frac{1}{x}, \; 2n\pi + \sin^{-1} \frac{1}{x}, \; \theta = 2n\pi + \sin^{-1} \frac{1}{2x}, \; \theta = (2n+1)\pi - \sin^{-1} \frac{1}{2x} $$
Now, you can finish it.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks!